# PHP: Export Table to Excel Without Hidden Columns

Tags: php, jquery, excel

I'm trying to export a table from PHP in Excel. Everything is fine, but I need to hide some columns, using JQuery, in PHP. When I export the table with hidden colums to Excel, the hidden columns appear with zero values.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
import_request_variables('P');
$title="Table Results";
$var= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$title.".xls";
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header($var);
echo $_POST['tableExcel'];
```

`tableExcel` is a form with the table.

Is there a way to not include hidden columns when I export to Excel?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using a library ? Else just don't put them in the data you export.

Comment: I'm guessing another example of useing PHP's automagic extension to convert HTML markup to an Excel file simply by setting headers and file extension. If you were creating a proper Excel BIFF file, you could actually set the columns as hidden

Comment: Actually I'm doing what Mark Baker says, just using HTML. So, are u suggesting to use another library?

Comment: WRiting a real BIFF file would be one option, parsing the table and removing the columns you don't want would be another

Comment: Thank you very much... I'll do some research to find the way to do what I need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
```

This is not an HTML filetype. In order to manipulate HTML, a script command or inline script is required within the HTML to able to call the jQuery. Unless your Excel program has some sort of jQuery emulator, you are asking to do something that is not possible for this filetype.

If this was HTML however, you could do this:

```
$('#myColumnId').css('display','none');
```